# How to set fetchPolicy globally on apollo-client queries?

Tags: graphql-js, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a few mutations that should trigger some refetchQueries, but I need those queries to have a fetchPolicy other than the default.

Is there a way to set [fetchPolicy](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.query) globally instead of per query? So to avoid setting fetchPolicy on each query.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is now possible!

```
const defaultOptions = { 
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: 'all'
  }
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  defaultOptions,
})
```

See documentation: [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#example-defaultoptions-object)

Comment: I cannot find it here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html#configuration

Comment: If am applying both default and query level policy which policy will be applied ?